# How can i make the Button check if other buttons clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want when i click ( connect ) button to check if (klein_auto_1) Button clicked and (klein_anhaenger_4) clicked then alert that 
and the other buttons also the same things
i have tried but i got always the same alert 
Example ( when i click connect Button check if klein_auto_2 Button and klein_anhaenger_3 is clicked then alert a2 + a3  but i got always the same alert for all buttons

i'm sorry for my bad English language

```js
$(function() {
  $("#klein_auto_1").on("click", function() {
    $("#gross_auto").attr("id", "gross_auto_a1");
  });

  $("#klein_auto_2").click(function() {
    $("#gross_auto").attr("id", "gross_auto_a2");
  });

  $("#klein_auto_3").click(function() {
    $("#gross_auto").attr("id", "gross_auto_a3");
  });

  $("#klein_auto_4").click(function() {
    $("#gross_auto").attr("id", "gross_auto_a4");
  });

  $("#gross_auto").click(function() {
    $("#gross_auto_a1").attr("id", "gross_auto");
    $("#gross_auto_a2").attr("id", "gross_auto");
    $("#gross_auto_a3").attr("id", "gross_auto");
    $("#gross_auto_a4").attr("id", "gross_auto");
  });

  $("#klein_anhaenger_1").click(function() {
    $("#gross_anhaenger").attr("id", "gross_anhaenger_a1");
  });

  $("#klein_anhaenger_2").click(function() {
    $("#gross_anhaenger").attr("id", "gross_anhaenger_a2");
  });

  $("#klein_anhaenger_3").click(function() {
    $("#gross_anhaenger").attr("id", "gross_anhaenger_a3");
  });

  $("#klein_anhaenger_4").click(function() {
    $("#gross_anhaenger").attr("id", "gross_anhaenger_a4");
  });

  $("#gross_anhaenger").click(function() {
    $("#gross_anhaenger_a1").attr("id", "gross_anhaenger");
    $("#gross_anhaenger_a2").attr("id", "gross_anhaenger");
    $("#gross_anhaenger_a3").attr("id", "gross_anhaenger");
    $("#gross_anhaenger_a4").attr("id", "gross_anhaenger");
  });

  $("#connect").click(function() {
    if ($("#gross_auto_a1").length && ('#gross_anhaenger_a1').length) {
      alert("a1+ a1");
    } else if ($("#gross_auto_a1").length && ('#gross_anhaenger_a2').length) {
      alert("a1+ a2");
    } else if ($("#gross_auto_a1").length && ('#gross_anhaenger_a3').length) {
      alert("a1+ a3");
    } else if ($("#gross_auto_a1").length && ('#gross_anhaenger_a4').length) {
      alert("a1+ a4");
    } else if ($("#gross_auto_a2").length && ('#gross_anhaenger_a1').length) {
      alert("a1+ a1");
    } else if ($("#gross_auto_a2").length && ('#gross_anhaenger_a2').length) {
      alert("a1+ a2");
    } else if ($("#gross_auto_a2").length && ('#gross_anhaenger_a3').length) {
      alert("a1+ a3");
    } else if ($("#gross_auto_a2").length && ('#gross_anhaenger_a4').length) {
      alert("a1+ a4");
    } else if ($("#gross_auto_a3").length && ('#gross_anhaenger_a1').length) {
      alert("a1+ a1");
    } else if ($("#gross_auto_a3").length && ('#gross_anhaenger_a2').length) {
      alert("a1+ a2");
    } else if ($("#gross_auto_a3").length && ('#gross_anhaenger_a3').length) {
      alert("a1+ a3");
    } else if ($("#gross_auto_a4").length && ('#gross_anhaenger_a4').length) {
      alert("a1+ a4");
    } else if ($("#gross_auto_a4").length && ('#gross_anhaenger_a1').length) {
      alert("a1+ a1");
    } else if ($("#gross_auto_a4").length && ('#gross_anhaenger_a2').length) {
      alert("a1+ a2");
    } else if ($("#gross_auto_a4").length && ('#gross_anhaenger_a3').length) {
      alert("a1+ a3");
    } else if ($("#gross_auto_a4").length && ('#gross_anhaenger_a4').length) {
      alert("a1+ a4");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  /* Firefox 2+ */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;
  /* Standard syntax */
  user-drag: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
}

#picturelayer {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#image {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

#index {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/*
#auto {
        position: absolute;
        width: 40vw;
        height: 75vh;
        top: 20%;
        left: 5%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-style: solid;
}
*/

#h1 {
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 5%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#gross_auto {
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 32vh;
  top: 20%;
  left: 5%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-style: solid;
  display: none;
}

#gross_auto_a1 {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("../images/1.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 32vh;
  top: 20%;
  left: 5%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-style: solid;
  display: block;
}

#gross_auto_a2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("../images/2.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 32vh;
  top: 20%;
  left: 5%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-style: solid;
  display: block;
}

#gross_auto_a3 {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("../images/3.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 32vh;
  top: 20%;
  left: 5%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-style: solid;
  display: block;
}

#gross_auto_a4 {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("../images/4.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 32vh;
  top: 20%;
  left: 5%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-style: solid;
  display: block;
}


/*
#klein_auto {
        position: relative;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        width: 38vw;
        height: 28vh;
        top: 2%;
        bottom: 1%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-style: solid;
}
*/

#klein_auto_1 {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("../images/1.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 11vw;
  height: 14vh;
  top: 56%;
  left: 5.5%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-style: solid;
}

#klein_auto_2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("../images/2.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 11vw;
  height: 14vh;
  top: 56%;
  left: 23.6%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-style: solid;
}

#klein_auto_3 {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("../images/3.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 11vw;
  height: 14vh;
  top: 75%;
  left: 5.5%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-style: solid;
}

#klein_auto_4 {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("../images/4.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 11vw;
  height: 14vh;
  top: 75%;
  left: 23.6%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-style: solid;
}


/*
#anhaenger {
        position: absolute;
        width: 40vw;
        height: 75vh;
        top: 20%;
        right: 5%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-style: solid;
}
*/

#gross_anhaenger {
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 32vh;
  top: 20%;
  right: 5%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-style: solid;
  display: none;
}

#gross_anhaenger_a1 {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("../images/5.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 32vh;
  top: 20%;
  right: 5%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-style: solid;
  display: block;
}

#gross_anhaenger_a2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("../images/6.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 32vh;
  top: 20%;
  right: 5%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-style: solid;
  display: block;
}

#gross_anhaenger_a3 {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("../images/7.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 32vh;
  top: 20%;
  right: 5%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-style: solid;
  display: block;
}

#gross_anhaenger_a4 {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("../images/8.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 32vh;
  top: 20%;
  right: 5%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-style: solid;
  display: block;
}

#klein_anhaenger_1 {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("../images/5.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 11vw;
  height: 14vh;
  top: 56%;
  right: 23.6%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-style: solid;
}

#klein_anhaenger_2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("../images/6.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 11vw;
  height: 14vh;
  top: 56%;
  right: 5.5%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-style: solid;
}

#klein_anhaenger_3 {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("../images/7.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 11vw;
  height: 14vh;
  top: 75%;
  right: 23.6%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-style: solid;
}

#klein_anhaenger_4 {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("../images/8.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 11vw;
  height: 14vh;
  top: 75%;
  right: 5.5%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-style: solid;
}

#connect {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("../images/connect.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 8vw;
  height: 6vh;
  top: 35%;
  left: 46%;
}

#result {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: none;
}

#image_result {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

area {
  outline: none;
}


/*
html, body {
            margin: 0;
            border: 0;
            padding: 0;
}

html {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
}

body {
        background-color: black;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -webkit-user-select: none;/* Safari 3.1+ 
        -moz-user-select: -moz-none; /* Firefox 2+ 
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ 
        user-select: none; /* Standard syntax 
        user-drag: none; 
        -webkit-user-drag: none;
}
 

#picturelayer {
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
}

#image {
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: block;
}

.index {
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
}


#auto {
        position: absolute;
        width: 40vw;
        height: 75vh;
        top: 20%;
        left: 5%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-style: solid;
}

.h1 {
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 5%;
    margin: 0 auto;    
}

.h2 {
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 5%;
    margin: 0 auto;    
}

.gross_auto {
        position: absolute;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        width: 30vw;
        height: 32vh;
        top: 20%;
        left: 5%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-style: solid;
        display: none;
}

.gross_auto_a1 {
        position: absolute;
        background-image: url("../images/1.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        width: 30vw;
        height: 32vh;
        top: 20%;
        left: 5%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-style: solid;
        display: block;
}

.gross_auto_a2 {
        position: absolute;
        background-image: url("../images/2.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        width: 30vw;
        height: 32vh;
        top: 20%;
        left: 5%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-style: solid;
        display: block;
}

.gross_auto_a3 {
        position: absolute;
        background-image: url("../images/3.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        width: 30vw;
        height: 32vh;
        top: 20%;
        left: 5%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-style: solid;
        display: block;
}

.gross_auto_a4 {
        position: absolute;
        background-image: url("../images/4.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        width: 30vw;
        height: 32vh;
        top: 20%;
        left: 5%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-style: solid;
        display: block;
}


#klein_auto {
        position: relative;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        width: 38vw;
        height: 28vh;
        top: 2%;
        bottom: 1%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-style: solid;
}

.klein_auto_1 {
        position: absolute;
        background-image: url("../images/1.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        width: 11vw;
        height: 14vh;
        top: 56%;
        left: 5.5%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-style: solid;
}

.klein_auto_2 {
        position: absolute;
        background-image: url("../images/2.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        width: 11vw;
        height: 14vh;
        top: 56%;
        left: 23.6%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-style: solid;
}

.klein_auto_3 {
        position: absolute;
        background-image: url("../images/3.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        width: 11vw;
        height: 14vh;
        top: 75%;
        left: 5.5%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-style: solid;
}

.klein_auto_4 {
        position: absolute;
        background-image: url("../images/4.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        width: 11vw;
        height: 14vh;
        top: 75%;
        left: 23.6%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-style: solid;
}

/*
#anhaenger {
        position: absolute;
        width: 40vw;
        height: 75vh;
        top: 20%;
        right: 5%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-style: solid;
}

.gross_anhaenger {
        position: absolute;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        width: 30vw;
        height: 32vh;
        top: 20%;
        right: 5%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-style: solid;
        display: none;
}

.klein_anhaenger_1 {
        position: absolute;
        background-image: url("../images/5.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        width: 11vw;
        height: 14vh;
        top: 56%;                                           
        right: 23.6%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-style: solid;
}

.klein_anhaenger_2 {
        position: absolute;
        background-image: url("../images/6.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        width: 11vw;
        height: 14vh;
        top: 56%;
        right: 5.5%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-style: solid;
}

.klein_anhaenger_3 {
        position: absolute;
        background-image: url("../images/7.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        width: 11vw;
        height: 14vh;
        top: 75%;
        right: 23.6%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-style: solid;
}

.klein_anhaenger_4 {
        position: absolute;
        background-image: url("../images/8.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        width: 11vw;
        height: 14vh;
        top: 75%;
        right: 5.5%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-style: solid;
}

.connect {
        position: absolute;
        background-image: url("../images/connect.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        width: 8vw;
        height: 6vh;
        top: 35%;
        left: 46%;
}

.result {
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: none;
}

.image_result {
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: block;
}
area { 
    outline: none;
}
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="picturelayer">

  <img id="image" src="images/0.png" border="0" orgwidth="1920" orgheight="1080" usemap="#image-maps-2016-09-02-023703" alt="" />
  <map name="image-maps-2016-09-02-023703" id="imagemapscom-image-maps-2016-09-02-023703">
    <div id="index">
      <div id="auto">
        <div id="gross_auto"></div>
        <div id ="klein_auto">
          <button id="klein_auto_1"></button>
          <button id="klein_auto_2"></button>
          <button id="klein_auto_3"></button>
          <button id="klein_auto_4"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="anhaenger">
        <div id="gross_anhaenger"></div>
        <div id="klein_anhaenger">
          <button id="klein_anhaenger_1"></button>
          <button id="klein_anhaenger_2"></button>
          <button id="klein_anhaenger_3"></button>
          <button id="klein_anhaenger_4"></button>
        </div>
      </div>        
      <h1 id="h1">welcome</h1>
      <button id="connect"></button>
    </div>
    <div id="result">
      <img id="image_result">
    </div>
  </map>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is impossible to understand your code. Can you please simplify it a bit and isolate only problematic code? I'd be happy to help, once I understand it.

Comment: ya i'm so sorry for that, i'm new with cods and also new hier.
My problem was solved.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
var kleinAuto;
var kleinAnhaenger;

$('.klein_auto').on('click', function (e) {
    kleinAuto = $(e.target) // Reference to clicked element by e.target
                 .attr('value'); // Get "value" attribute
});

$('.klein_anhaenger').on('click', function (e) {
    kleinAnhaenger = $(e.target).attr('value');
});

$('#connect').on('click', function () {
    if (kleinAuto === undefined || kleinAnhaenger === undefined) {
        alert('Please click buttons');
    } else {
        alert('Klein auto: ' + kleinAuto + ', Klein anhaenger: ' + kleinAnhaenger);
        // Reset
        kleinAuto = undefined;
        kleinAnhaenger = undefined;
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="auto">
            <div id="gross_auto"></div>
            <div id="klein_auto">
                <button class="klein_auto" value="1">1</button>
                <button class="klein_auto" value="2">2</button>
                <button class="klein_auto" value="3">3</button>
                <button class="klein_auto" value="4">4</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="anhaenger">
            <div id="gross_anhaenger"></div>
            <div id="klein_anhaenger">
                <button class="klein_anhaenger" value="1">1</button>
                <button class="klein_anhaenger" value="2">2</button>
                <button class="klein_anhaenger" value="3">3</button>
                <button class="klein_anhaenger" value="4">4</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button id="connect">Connect</button>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Other advice I would give you:

1. In your HTML you can have many CSS classes of the same type but only one Id of the same type per one page.
2. You should avoid writing repeated code because its difficult to understand it and maintain it.
3. Having your scripts at the end of `<body>` tag is a good practise especially when your code manipulates [DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp). Example: you have to render `<button>` first before you attach a function that is fired whenever you click the button.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!